# Krull dimension of Noetherian local rings is finite

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension, local-rings

> Does anyone know an "elementary" proof of the fact that a Noetherian local ring has finite Krull dimension?

The one I know is from Atiyah&Macdonald's book *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, where they use Hilbert functions (which is not an elementary proof). On the other hand, I am studying the local rings section of Weibel's book *Introduction to Homological Algebra*, where it says that if $R$ is a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and residue field $k$ then the Krull dimension of $R$ is bounded by $\dim_k\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$, and there is not any reference about that. This made me think that this could be easy to prove but I haven't succeeded.

Comment: The principal ideal theorem is also not horrible to prove. I feel like the treatment in Qing Liu's algebraic geometry book is nice and streamlined.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106866

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you *R. Y. Sharp*'s book: *Steps in Commutative Algebra*.

By Theorem 15.4 (*Krull's generalized principal ideal theorem*), $\dim R$ is less than or equal to "**the number of elements in each minimal generating set for $m$**", which is finite since $R$ is Noetherian. And by Proposition 9.3 this is equal to $\dim_k m/m^2$.